# Cannot Boot from Drive with Bootable Partition

Tags: linux-kernel, partition, bootable, distributions

I am working on developing my own, minimal Linux Distro. I have successfully compiled the kernel and set up GRUB to boot it. I have a drive `/dev/sda`. On partition 1 of that (64M), I have the GRUB image. On the second partition, which is ~3GB (it's a small drive), I have an ext4 file system with the minimum stuff needed to boot (`/sbin/init`, `/etc/inittab`, and a few programs to run on boot). Previously, I was able to successfully boot into a shell using `qemu-system-x86_64 -drive format=raw,cache=none,file=/dev/sda1 -drive format=raw,cache=none,file=/dev/sda2`. However, I decided to try and make it easier to boot, so I used `fdisk` and flagged `/dev/sda1` as bootable. However, when I do `qemu-system-x86_64 /dev/sda`, it hangs on `Booting from hard disk...`, and actually trying to boot from the drive just reboots my computer. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Grub does not use boot flag. Windows, syslinux & lilo do use boot flag as part of booting. Some BIOS/UEFI need a boot flag, they must assume Windows & Windows has to have a boot flag. Or boot flag should not have changed anything.

Comment: So is there some equivalent for GRUB? How can I make my computer/QEMU see the drive as bootable?

Comment: Should I be copying the GRUB image to `/dev/sda` instead of `/dev/sda1` so that the drive has a boot signature?

Comment: Grub has several parts. It is in MBR, but core.img is in sectors after MBR but before first partition. If using gpt partitioning, and BIOS boot, you have to have a bios_grub partition. Grub always is installed to a drive (so in MBR), not to a partition, but parts of it will be in the partition.

Comment: I think I found a solution. I made 3 partitions: a BIOS boot partition, a `/boot` partition, and an ordinary FS partition. I can boot the drive now, but the problem is GRUB cannot find the files on the `/boot` partition without me telling it to. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: If you manually install grub, you have to create your own  /boot/grub/grub.cfg. See: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.pdf Search in pdf for /boot/grub/ for lots of details.

Comment: I have my own `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, but it is on my `/boot` partition.

Comment: That is where it should be and then if boot stanza is correct it will boot. UEFI or BIOS boot? MBR or gpt partitioning?

Comment: I have it set up using GPT, and I am using BIOS. The problem is, the partition it boots from is different from the partition with `grub.cfg` on it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an alternative solution. Instead of booting from seperate partitions,  I just formatted the disk as ext4 then installed GRUB on it, where ext4 leaves empty space.